# Jackson MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, jackson-databind

I am trying to implement JWTAuthentication in my project. I have set up my entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class ApplicationUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String username,password;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Then I have setup the AuthenticationFilter like this:

```
    public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }

        @Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
            try {
                System.out.println("request "+request.getPathInfo());
                ApplicationUser user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),ApplicationUser.class);
//this is where the exception is    
                return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),new ArrayList<>()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String token = Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject(((ApplicationUser) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
                    .compact();
            response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
        }
    }
```

And this is my SecurityConfiguration as:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(AppUserDetailService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder){
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder=bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.userDetailsService=userDetailsService;
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
//                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

Sign up is working fine, but when I try to login using the same credentials I get the following exception:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
>        at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4145) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3070) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
>           at com.project.pq.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
>           ... 53 common frames omitted

I am using Postman to hit the API and there I have set application/json as the content-type and sent the username and password as post parameters. I am following [this](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) tutorial. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do not consume the POST content in a filter, especially not a filter that applies to all URLs. If logging in requires a POST to a specify URL with JSON content, then it should be handled by a Servlet, not a Filter. Authentication filters are for processing header values (e.g. `Authentication`), so authentication can happen on-the-fly, during the processing of any arbitrary request.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, had to remove 
    ApplicationUser user = new 
    ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),ApplicationUser.class);

and use request.getParameter directly:

```
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    request.getParameter("username"),
                    request.getParameter("password"),
                    Collections.emptyList()
            )
```

Comment: Have you found out the reason for this behaviour? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: replacing objectMapper line with request.getParameter("") worked like charm